# Indefinite retention in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, retention

My Director has come to me very late in a 365 deployment to ask to retain all data indefinitely. I have rejected this partially on GDPR grounds. Although we can set retention for GDPR data specifically.

My question then is, how could I possibly retain all data indefinitely?

I can stop deletion, but this becomes impossible to manage any data then, as files will be mis-created or need moving, its just unworkable.

Is it possible to extend the 2nd stage recycle bin time of the SharePoint Online?

I have tried to explain that any data that needs to be kept for regulatory reasons needs to be stored in a specific site with specific permissions and retention.

365 backups are another option, but I know this has GDPR issues, if we retain specific data in backups.

Answer (score 0):

This is really not a good idea to keep data retained indefinitely in SPO. You can definitely keep all data undeleted and try using as many libraries/lists as possible to keep them organized, but eventually it will slow down your whole tenant since there are plenty of [**limits** in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits).

Personally I give you a **Not possible** as the answer. The retention comes with a [93-day](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/office-365-sharepoint-online-data-deletion) time rage, as well as for the second-stage Recycle Bin, which is managed by Microsoft directly and cannot be extended.